# how to read only some specific columns from a csv file for example only from 72-84 in CAPL

Tags: capl, canoe

I am quite new to CAPL programming and i would like to know how can we extract just some specific column from a csv file

for example
i just need the readinds from 89 th to 99 th line just the column A how can i do that any helps would be appreciated
thanks in advance
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ChgzQ.png)

Comment: Could you please add some more information: what does the CSV file look like? Does it have a header, how are the columns separated? Do you need the content as string or as int, ...

Comment: hi thank you for replying no it doesnt has a header 33;1200                                                  f                                                                                 65;1600.... and so on separted by semicolon";" and i need those values as int  so that i can use those values to categorise to which group they belongs to